# Will this run out of process?

Tags: c#, wcf, out-of-memory, nancy

Have been looking for something that will allow me to run some processes out of memory (receiving out of memory exceptions on large data/process related work, and have tried all sorts of options), but also want the communication between host and newly created process. So though about self hosted WCF and this came up. [msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758(v=vs.110).aspx)

The question is, will this run in the same process or out of process (to me it looks like same process, that's where I thought I could host it inside Nancy)? Unless somebody can help with a better (read: neat) idea.